# How to generate Universal Dependency Relations using Stanford NLP tools using Java?

Tags: java, nlp, stanford-nlp

We have created the parse tree from the command line using this command :

```
java -mx1g -cp "*" edu.stanford.nlp.parser.lexparser.LexicalizedParser -sentences newline -tokenized -tagSeparator / -tokenizerFactory edu.stanford.nlp.process.WhitespaceTokenizer -tokenizerMethod newCoreLabelTokenizerFactory edu/stanford/nlp/models/lexparser/englishPCFG.ser.gz data/for.txt
```

and upto this we got the correct output of the input file as tree format.

But we want the output like : http://nlp.stanford.edu:8080/parser/

**Universal dependencies**
nmod:poss(dog-2, My-1)
nsubj(likes-4, dog-2)
advmod(likes-4, also-3)
root(ROOT-0, likes-4)
xcomp(likes-4, eating-5)
dobj(eating-5, sausage-6)
**Universal dependencies, enhanced**
nmod:poss(dog-2, My-1)
nsubj(likes-4, dog-2)
advmod(likes-4, also-3)
root(ROOT-0, likes-4)
xcomp(likes-4, eating-5)
dobj(eating-5, sausage-6)

Kindly share the JAVA code to produce this output.

Answer (score 1):

1. Download Stanford CoreNLP 3.6.0 from here:  http://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP
2. run this command from within the directory you just downloaded:

   ```
   java -Xmx3g -cp "*" edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP -annotators tokenize,ssplit,pos,lemma,ner,depparse -file sample_text.txt -outputFormat text
   ```